# Create Associative array with unique keys

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I'm creating an associative array (technically an object) like this, and the keys should be strings.

```
var j = <?php echo $max_key ?>;
var id = "ele"+j;
eleDetailsTop[id] = {id: id, size : "100%", sizeLabel : 12};
```

Finally this object will be stored in the DB as a JSON string.

My problem is generating a value for j. Keys will look like this `ele0, ele1, ele2...`etc. So, value of `j` It should be `+1` from the max value of the currently stored keys in the DB. Let's say the max value is `ele4`, the next value of `j` should be `5`. So, then I can generate new id as `ele5`

How to get this done ?

Comment: Maybe use the count of keys instead of the last key value (`id = "ele" + eleDetailsTop.length`)?

Comment: Have you tried JavaScript for loop?

Comment: Are you intending to have an associative array for use in javascript?

Comment: yes. Array or object. Whatever, something that support the data structure like this

Answer (score 0):

```
var max = <?php echo $max_key ?>;
var eleDetailsTop = [];
for (var id = 0; id < max; id++) {
  eleDetailsTop["ele" + id] = {id: id, size : "100%", sizeLabel : 12};
}
```